# FormsAuthentication problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I 'form authenticate' users like this in the controller:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(User.Email, false);
```

(provided that the credential are valid of course).

Usually, I can access the username of the user like this in a view (I just started to use razor):

```
@Html.Encode(Page.User.Identity.Name)
```

Unfortunately, I get:

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

I presume that:

```
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(User.Email, false);
```

did not work correctly (login and consequent redirect work fine though).

Can anyone see something wrong? Thanks!

Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use Page. You have access to User from within the view on its own.

```
@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, came across this when converting aspx pages to razor views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. I would suggest passing the username in as part of your ViewModel though instead of escaping into Asp.Net framework territory.

Comment: could you please explain why that's a bad idea?

Comment: The view should know as little as possible about it's environment. By passing it into a view via a model you can change the source of the username without having to update all the views that rely on it, for instance. You just need to update the model.

Comment: Problem is that the username is written by the masterpage. how do you send the viewdata in this case?